# Custom CSS timeline with odd / even styling

Tags: html, css

I want to remove the first line from the CSS timeline I created, I just want the timeline circle to show up first not to have a line before it. I also want to style each dot different color, how can I do both these?

I have tried to add a class to one of the timeline containers called .not_complete but it doesnt change the color of the circle of the timeline.

```css
/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timelinex {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timelinex:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.timelinex::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* Container around content */
.containerx {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

/* The circles on the timeline */
.containerx::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.containerx::after .not_complete {
  background-color: #e3e3e3 !important;
}

/* Place the container to the left */
.leftx {
  left: 0;
}

/* Place the container to the right */
.rightx {
  left: 50%;
}

/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.rightx::after {
  left: -7px;
}

/* The actual content */
.contentx {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timelinex">
  <div class="containerx leftx not_complete">
    <div class="contentx">
      <p>
        <img src="assets/img/therapist1.jpg" style="border-radius: 0.5em;border-top-left-radius: 120px; border-bottom-right-radius: 120px">
      </p>
      <h5 style="color:#999;font-style: 0.5em"> DAY 1 </h5>
      <div> Test Timeline Step 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector here is invalid:

```
.containerx::after .not_complete {
```

It would select the child of the `::after` pseudo element. You need to use:

```
.containerx.not_complete::after {
```

The above selector selects any element's `::after` pseudo element, with the classes `containerx` and `not_complete`. So kindly replace your code with:

```
.containerx.not_complete::after {
  background-color: #e3e3e3 !important;
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.

**Complete Snippet**

```css
/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timelinex {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-bottom: 5em;
}

/* The actual timeline (the vertical ruler) */
.timelinex:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}


.timelinex::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

/* Container around content */
.containerx {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
  width: 50%;
}

/* The circles on the timeline */
.containerx::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  right: -5px;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  top: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.containerx.not_complete::after {
  background-color: #e3e3e3 !important;
}


/* Place the container to the left */
.leftx {
  left: 0;
}

/* Place the container to the right */
.rightx {
  left: 50%;
}


/* Fix the circle for containers on the right side */
.rightx::after {
  left: -7px;
}

/* The actual content */
.contentx {
  padding: 2px 3px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timelinex" >
  <div class="containerx leftx not_complete">
    <div class="contentx">
      <p><img src="assets/img/therapist1.jpg" style="border-radius: 0.5em;border-top-left-radius: 120px; border-bottom-right-radius: 120px"></p>
      <h5 style="color:#999;font-style: 0.5em"> DAY 1 </h5>
      <div> Test Timeline Step 1</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** For Even / Odd Styling and First Child.

To create odd and even styling, you need to use `:nth-child()` selector. An example of having it blue and red is here:

```css
li {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}
li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #00f;
}
li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f00;
}
li:first-child {
  background: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First Child</li>
  <li>Even</li>
  <li>Odd</li>
  <li>Even</li>
  <li>Odd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, how would I remove the line from sticking out at the top on the first circle... i.e. how do I edit the style of the timeline line for each div?

Comment: @condo1234 With your code I am unable to find the line. Can you show me a working example, so that I can help you better?

Comment: The line is in .timelinex::after

Comment: @condo1234 So you mean, you don't want the line for the first div?

Comment: @condo1234 Try this? `.timelinex:first-child::after {display: none;}`. Let me know if that works. Thanks.

Comment: That hides the entire timeline

Comment: @condo1234 Can you show an example with few timeline entries in CodePen or JSFiddle please?